# Using BubbleWrap::HTTP to send device's location when app entered background

Tags: ios5, ios6, cllocationmanager, rubymotion

In my app I want to submit the device's location when in background to a web app. Currently I am using [BubbleWrap](https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap) for the POST request.

**Note, that I may be able to use anything other than BubbleWrap if needed.**

The current behavior is the following:

1. I start up the app
2. I bring it to background
3. [Waiting for request on web app, watching the logs, nothing happens]
4. I bring the app to the foreground
5. The app sends the device's location

What should happen:

1. I start up the app
2. I bring it to background
3. The app sends the device's location
4. The app keeps listening for significant location changes and sends its location on significant change

This is the code:

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    [ommitted]
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)

    true
  end

  def applicationDidEnterBackground(application)
    @locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
  end

  def applicationDidEnterForeground
    @locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
  end

  def application(app, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken)
    @device_token = deviceToken.description.gsub(" ", "").gsub("<", "").gsub(">", "")

    # Log the push notification to the console
    puts @device_token
  end

  def application(app, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error)
    show_alert "Error when registering for device token", "Error, #{error}"
  end

  def device_token
    @device_token
  end

  def location_manager
    if @locationManager.nil?
      @locationManager = CLLocationManager.alloc.init
      @locationManager.setDesiredAccuracy(KCLLocationAccuracyBest)
      @locationManager.delegate = self
    end
    @locationManager
  end

  # iOS >= 4
  def locationManager(manager, didUpdateToLocation:current_location, fromLocation:last_location)
    puts "Location #{current_location} [iOS 5]"
  end

  # iOS >= 6
  def locationManager(manager, didUpdateLocations:locations)
    data = {latitude: locations.last.coordinate.latitude,
            longitude: locations.last.coordinate.longitude,
            device_token: @device_token }
    BW::HTTP.post("http://192.168.1.100:4567/", {payload: data}) do |response|
      if response.ok?
        #json = BW::JSON.parse(response.body.to_str)
        #p json['id']
      else
        App.alert(response.error_message)
      end
    end
  end

  def locationManager(manager, didFailWithError:error)
    puts "failed"
  end

  def show_alert(title, message)
    alert = UIAlertView.new
    alert.title = title
    alert.message = message
    alert.show
  end
end
```

Additional info:

- I have declared the following in my Rakefile `app.info_plist['UIBackgroundModes'] = ['location']`.

Any hints or tips on why this is may not be working?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that because the BW::HTTP.post(...) is asynchronous, your app quits before the block is called.

Comment: What would you suggest as a/an solution/alternative?

Comment: this might help? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2277/_index.html